# Тратится ли inode при создании жесткой ссылки (hard link)?

Tags: linux, файловая-система

Тратится ли inode при создании жесткой ссылки (hard link)?
Если да, то почему тратятся?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создадим файл-ссылку с именем hardlink1, которая будет указывать на уже существующий файл file1:

```
$ ln file1 hardlink1
```

Что бы убедиться, что по сути оба файла являются одним и тем же объектом файловой системы — сравним их inode-номер, в данном случае — это номер 475949:

```
$ ls -lih | grep 475949
475949 -rw-r--r--  2 root     setevoy     0B Aug 13 11:51 file1
475949 -rw-r--r--  2 root     setevoy     0B Aug 13 11:51 hardlink1
```

Как видим — оба файла с разными именами, но имеют общий inode.

В момент создания жесткой ссылки с помощью утилиты ln в файл директории добавляется дополнительная запись. Новое имя файла ставится в соответствие **существующей** структуре inode.
Структура inode содержит счетчик, использующийся для подсчета количества жестких ссылок на нее. В момент, когда значение счетчика уменьшается до нуля, содержимое структуры inode очищается.

Comment: Касается ли это всех ОС и всех файловых систем, где есть понятие inode?

Comment: @andreymal, насколько знаю - да.